# Ignore specific node within array when the element inside the node has a specific value while comparing two JSON in Java

Tags: java, json, comparator, jsonassert

I am trying to compare two JSON structures using Custom comparator of JSONAssert package. For example,
Data1:

```
{
  "name": "John",
  "details": {
    "age": 30,
    "State": {
      "City": "Buffalo",
      "Country" :[ 
        {
        "Classification" : "USA",
        "Data" : "sample1"
        },
        {
        "Classification" : "Canada",
        "Data" : "sample1"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I want to ignore the whole array index 0 when the classification has the value "USA" i.e I want to ignore even the data field in the first element of a country when the classification value is "USA".

```
    public void compareJsonStrIgnoringDiffInArray() throws JSONException {
        String errorMsg = "";
        String expectedJsonStr = "{\"name\":\"John\",\"details\":{\"age\":30,\"State\":{\"City\":\"Buffalo\",\"Country\":[{\"Classification\":\"USA\",\"Data\":\"sample1\"},{\"Classification\":\"Canada\",\"Data\":\"sample1\"}]}}}";

        String actualJsonStr = "{\"name\":\"John\",\"details\":{\"age\":30,\"State\":{\"City\":\"Buffalo\",\"Country\":[{\"Classification\":\"USA\",\"Data\":\"sample1\"},{\"Classification\":\"Canada\",\"Data\":\"sample1\"}]}}}";

        //Create custom comparator which compares two json strings but ignores reporting any differences for anArray[n].id values
        //as they are a tolerated difference

        ArrayValueMatcher<Object> arrValMatch = new ArrayValueMatcher<>(new CustomComparator(
                JSONCompareMode.NON_EXTENSIBLE,
                new Customization("Country[*].classification", (o1, o2) -> true)));

        Customization arrayValueMatchCustomization = new Customization("Country", arrValMatch);
        CustomComparator customArrayValueComparator = new CustomComparator(
                JSONCompareMode.NON_EXTENSIBLE, 
                arrayValueMatchCustomization);
        JSONAssert.assertEquals(expectedJsonStr, actualJsonStr, customArrayValueComparator);
    }
```

I have tried this implementation but it ignores all the classification values in every index. But i only want one index to be ignored including the data element when the classification value is "USA".

Ref: [Ignore specific node within array when comparing two JSON in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50919776/ignore-specific-node-within-array-when-comparing-two-json-in-java)